# oxyplot is throwing an error at design-time, issue with namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am working on a WPF app in which I would like to integrate OxyPlot. 
I have pulled OxyPlot into my project by using the relative nuget package.
Curious thing is that the package Oxy.Core and Oxy.Wpf are available only as prereleases.

Moreover, after installation the page is modified to include in the top part:

```
xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
```

and the content to host the actual chart:

```
<Grid Margin="190, 10" Grid.Row="0" >
   <oxy:PlotView />
</Grid>
```

However, at design-time, I get this error:

> The name "PlotView" does not exist in the namespace
>   "http://oxyplot.org/wpf".

Any idea what is the issue here?

Cheers,

Gian

Answer (score 1):

The control `PlotView` used to be called `Plot`. So depending on the version you are using its one or the other.

http://www.oxyplot.org/announcements/plotview

Since you cannot find `PlotView` i assume you have an old version and need to use `Plot`

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace in XAML

```
<Window
...
xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <oxy:PlotView x:Name="plot1"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Model="{Binding PlotModelAllSensors}" 
                  BorderBrush="Aqua"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```